# How to make an IsEmpty-method in C# (double linked list)

Tags: c#, linked-list, reverse, is-empty

I want to reverse a list and to do that I take the first element of the list (head) and add it to a new list and then I delete the head of the first list and then I make a recursive call until the first list is empty which should mean that all elements have been copied to the new list. However my `IsEmpty` method is not working as intended and looks like this:

```
public bool IsEmpty()
{
    if (head != null!)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

When I write: `if (head != null) { ... }` it causes an error and prints out the following:

> Unhandled exception. System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

But if I write: `if (head.next != null)` it correctly prints out the whole list - except for the last element which is then being skipped. This does not make any sense to me. Can anyone help me understand why `head != null` is not working then?

For reference of my reverse list method:

```
public DoubleLinkedList ReverseList(DoubleLinkedList oldList, DoubleLinkedList newList)
{
    newList.InsertFront(oldList.head.Item);
    oldList.DeleteFirstNode();

    while (!oldList.IsEmpty())
    {
         ReverseList(oldList, newList);
    }

    return newList;
}
```

edit:
I have already posted the IsEmpty-method, I have not altered it or anything. And as have been requsted I post the rest of the methods that I use in ReverseList():

```
public void InsertFront(Item item) {
    Node newNode = new Node(item);
    newNode.next = head;
    if (head != null!) {
        head.prev = newNode;
    }
    head = newNode;
}
```

and

```
public void DeleteFirstNode() {
    Node temp = head;
    if (temp != null!) {
       head = temp.next;
       head.prev = null!;
       return;
    }
}
```

InsertFront() should work just fine though. It does as I expect it too. And I have also checked that DeleteFirstNode() actually does delete the first element of the list, but maybe there is some problem that I have not considered in this method.

edit: the issue has been fixed now. There was a bug in DeleteFirstNode() which should look like this in stead:

```
public void DeleteFirstNode() {
    Node temp = head;
    if (temp.next != null!) {
       head = temp.next;
       head.prev = null!;
       return;
    }
    else {
       head = null!;
    }
}
```

This caused ReverseList() to work correctly!

Comment: Can you post the actual `IsEmpty`? This should not throw a nullrefexception.

Comment: It would make more sense if it were the opposite from what you say in the second paragraph. Yes, please provide the version of the code that causes the error. It will also help if you post the code for your `InsertFront` and `DeleteFirstNode` methods, and provide driver code with which you get that error. That way we can reproduce it.

Comment: Side note: `IsEmpty => head is null;` is a shorter version.

Comment: I suspect a bug in `DoubleLinkedList.DeleteFirstNode()`.

Comment: By the way, you shouldn't write `null !` when you really mean a null value.

Comment: Even though I removed the "!" from null, it did not make any difference concerning my problem. But is there any difference?

Also: how do you highlight text in your replies?

Comment: I have solved the issue now. You were right that it was a bug in DeleteFirstNode(). I have fixed it by letting it check for temp.next != null! (rather than temp != null!) - if temp is null it will simply make head = null!